# django return the most recent record of each user

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am learning django framework, and currently I am facing a problem.

There are two models

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ...

class Action(models.Model):
    user = models.Foreign(User)
    action = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    createTime = models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)
```

Each action from each user is inserted into Action Model, therefore, there are lots of records of each user in Action by different createTime.

Now, I would like to list the latest action of each user, but I have no idea to implement it.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like:

```
from django.db.models import F, Max


actions = Action.objects.annotate(
    most_recent=Max('user__action__createTime')
).filter(createTime=F('most_recent'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query `Action` with the user you want info on, like this

```
actions = Action.objects.filter(user=selected_user).order_by("-createTime")
```

This will sort user actions by date in descending order, to get the latest action:

```
actions.first()
```